# 'set' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, множества

Здравствуйте!
По книге М.Луца изучаю Python, дошел до хронометража функций, из книги записываем модуль организующий функцию хронометража:

```
import time, sys

trace = lambda *args: None  # or print
timefunc = time.clock if sys.platform == 'win32' else time.time


def timer(func, *pargs, _reps=1000, **kargs):
    trace(func, pargs, kargs, _reps)
    start = timefunc()
    for i in range(_reps):
        ret = func(*pargs, **kargs)
    elapsed = timefunc() - start
    return (elapsed, ret)


def best(func, *pargs, _reps=50, **kargs):
    best = 2 ** 32
    for i in range(_reps):
        (time, ret) = timer(func, *pargs, _reps=1, **kargs)
        if time < best: best = time
        return (best, ret)
```

И так же дается код модуля который выводит результаты хронометража генератора списка, функции-генератора, функции map, цикла for, выражения - генератора. И на самостоятельное изучение Луц предлагает провести хронометраж генератора множества и генератора словаря, вот с выводом результатов по ним у меня и возникла ошибка 'set' object does not support indexing

Модуль Луца с добавленными мной генераторами множества и словаря:

```
import sys, Mytimer
reps = 10000
repslist = range(reps)

def forLoop():
    res =[]
    for x in repslist:
        res.append(x+10)
    return res

def listComp():
    return [x+10 for x in repslist]

def mapCall():
    return list(map((lambda x: x+10), repslist))

def genExpr():
    return list(x+10 for x in repslist)

def genFunc():
    def gen():
        for x in repslist:
            yield x+10
    return list(gen())

def setGen():
    return {x+10 for x in repslist} # добавлен мной

def dictGen():
    return {x: x+10 for x in repslist} # добавлен мной

print(sys.version)
for tester in (Mytimer.timer, Mytimer.best):
    print('<{0}>'.format(tester.__name__))
    for test in( forLoop, listComp, mapCall, genExpr, genFunc, setGen, dictGen):
        elapsed, result = tester(test)
        print('-'* 35)
        print('{0:<9}: {1:.5f} => [{2}...{3}]'.format(test.__name__, elapsed, result[0], result[-1])) # в этой строке находит ошибку 'set' object does not support indexing
```

Выводит весь хронометраж правильно,только без генератора множества и генератора словаря:

```
3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
<timer>
-----------------------------------
forLoop  : 1.35337 => [10...10009]
-----------------------------------
listComp : 0.79675 => [10...10009]
-----------------------------------
mapCall  : 1.50909 => [10...10009]
-----------------------------------
genExpr  : 1.12907 => [10...10009]
-----------------------------------
genFunc  : 1.15319 => [10...10009]
-----------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User1/PycharmProjects/Python36/chronoFunc.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(' % -9s: % .5f' % (test.__name__, elapsed, result[0], result[-1]))
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина в том, что множества не поддерживают обращение по индексу, поэтому можно из множества сделать список, тогда проблема будет решена

Пример:

```
result = list(result)
print('{0:<9}: {1:.5f} => [{2}...{3}]'.format(test.__name__, elapsed, result[0], result[-1]))
```